# How to retrieve image from the specified image path in Iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi how can i retrieve image from specified image path in iphone. In my code is

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)UIPicker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)info editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    imageView.image=info;
    [UIPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"UImage path= %@",imageView.image);
    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
    NSString* imageName = @"MyImage.png";
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];
    NSLog(@"Image path = %@",fullPathToFile);
}
```

When i select image, the image should be placed, it will successfully placed to uiimage view. And i got the image path.

When i execute the application in console it showed

```
Image path=document = /Users/rr-mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/46C716D0-13E9-4DF2-BC46-F1071DFCE14C/Documents/MyImage.png
```

My image is stored in this specified path. Here how can i retrieve this image and placed to imageview. Anybody help me to give the code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the UIImage in directory path, you should use :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPathToFile];
```

Full Code :

```
NSString *imageName = @"MyImage.png";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPathToFile];
self.imageView.image = image;
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in your question itself.

```
  NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

  fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

   imageView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:fullPathToFile];
```

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  NSString* imageNames = @"MyImage.png";

 NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
               NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 
 fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageNames];
 
 imageView.image =  [UIImageView imageNamed:fullPathToFile]; 
 
 }

Its not working

Answer (score 0):

If your image is placed under documents folder of your application you could use the following code,

```
yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];
```

Comment: yourImageView.image = [UIImageView imageNamed:@"/Users/rr-mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/46C716D0-13E9-4DF2-BC46-F1071DFCE14C/Documents/MyImage.png"];


is right this code?

Comment: No, you don't have to specify the full path, just use the code as it is.

Comment: Its not a UIImage. Its the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

To your comment in the previous answer, I am adding this

Get the doc directory by

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docdirpath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Append the image path to this docdirpath and then use it in `imageNamed:` method in UIImage.